# Number of Passes for Perceptron

Tags: algorithm, machine-learning, neural-network, perceptron

I am trying to implement Perceptron Algorithm but I am not able to figure out following points.

- what should be ideal value for iteration number
- is this algorithm suitable for large volumes of data?
- does threshold changes with iterations?
- if yes what difference does it make in final output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Perceptron is not a specific algorithm, it's a name of a cluster of algorithms. There're 2 major differences between these algorithms.

**1. Integrate and fire rule**

Let the input vector be `x`, the weights vector be `w`, the threshold be `t` and the output value be `P(x)`. There're various function to calculate P(x):

1. binary:  `P(x)` = 1 (if `w` * `x`>=`t`) or 0 (otherwise)
2. semi-linear: `P(x)` = `w` * `x` (if `w` * `x`>=`t`) or 0 (otherwise)
3. hard limit: `P(x)` = `t`(if `w` * `x`>=`t`) or `w` * `x` (if 0<`w` * `x`<`t`) or 0 (otherwise)
4. Sigmoid: `P(x)` = 1 / 1+e^(`w` * `x`)

and many others. **So it's hard to say what difference does the threshold make in final ouptut, because it depends on which integrate and fire function you use.**

**2. Learning rule**

The learning rule of the Perceptron is various too. The most simple and common one is

`w` ->  `w`+ `a` * `x`* (`D(x)`- `P(x)`)

where `a` is the size of a learning step, and `D(x)` is the expected output to `x`. **So it's also hard to say that what should be a ideal value of iterations, because it depends on the value of `a` and how many training samples you do have.**

Therefore, does thresold changes with iterations? **it also depends.** The simple and common learning rule above doesn't modify the threshold while training, but there're some other learning rules do modify it.

Btw, you also asked that is this algorothm suitable for large volume of data? **The main metrics to measure the suitability of a classifier for certain dataset, is the *linear separability* of the dataset, not the scale of it.** Keep in mind that the Single-layer Perceptron has very bad performance for the datasets which are not linear separable.  **The scale of the dataset does NOT that matter.**

Comment: is there anything using which i can roughly estimate number of passes? i am using this rule 1.binary: P(x) = 1 (if w * x>=t) or 0 (otherwise)  ..can i specify weights for individual nodes?

Comment: No, and we even don't have a objective method to determine the step size. That depends on experiments and experience. That's a crucial problem in the field of ANN. But in generally speaking - 1)the more samples, the less step size; 2) the more step size, the less training passes.

Comment: hmmmmm ok..can you give me one simple example which clearly explains weights and passes it would be great help...if not will continue trying

Comment: For example, consider a Perceptron with 2 inputs and threshold of 0.5 . If you want it to act as an AND gate, then the 2 weights would be say 0.3 .Else if you want it to act as an OR gate, then the 2 weights would be say 0.8 .

Comment: the weights are not determined by people, they are learned by the algorithm itself. That's why we call ANN as a **learning** algorithm. Just set them to 0 or random number, and use samples to train them to be right value. That's the basic knowledge of ANN, you might want to read some text books.

Comment: i already read about it..at what iteration you will get your weights right thats where i am stuck and confused you already answered this but still i am not clear :(

Comment: For example, let's say the AND gate with threshold 0.5 and step size 0.1. If the current weights are (0.6, 0.6), obviously that's wrong. With an input (1,0), you expect an output 0, but the perceptron output is 1 (1*0.6 + 0*0.6 > threshold 0.5). So the new weights would be `(0.6, 0.6) +  0.1 * (1, 0) * (0 - 1) = (0.5, 0.6)`. After a few samples training like this, the weights will be right. This learning function has been already given in my above answer.

Comment: i am using 1k data as a samplle but its taking 10-15 mins to run which is very slow ..can it run more faster than this?

Comment: You didn't show your code at all, how can I tell you anything about the performance of it....

Comment: actually code is in ECL language thats why i dindt post.shall i do ?

Comment: If you like, post it as another question that like **why is this code so slow?**, and tag it with `ECL`.

Comment: i am searching for some good examples on which i can apply single perceptron and clarify my doubts but not getting any

Comment: the AND/OR gate is for good example. I have tried to solve all of your questions, but you have not yet accepted or voted my answer. Well good luck:-)

Comment: yea sorry for that actually i forgot :( ....i want some real life example where perceptron can be applied..if you know any please update

Comment: please read this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/241032/what-are-some-practical-applications-for-a-…

Comment: thanx..already read it...still to read what is kernel perceptron

Comment: actually you don't have to. the kernel-based methods are crucial, but not for beginners. simple perceptron can solve a lot of linear classification, just search "linear classification problem" for them.

Comment: what is a epoch? I have not heard this term in the field of ANN before.

Comment: it's even not a parameter, it's at most a trick. if you don't know how to tune it, it's just ok to fix it to 1. To be honest, I think you don't understand the basic mechanism of perceptron or ANN. You'd better read more text books.